# Facebook Messenger -- Node to Ruby (Sinatra) GET example

Tags: ruby, facebook, messenger, facebook-messenger

```
app.get('webhook/', function (req, res) {
  if (req.query['hub.verify_token'] === 'this_is_my_marker_for_confirmation') {
    res.send(req.query['hub.challenge']);
  }
  res.send('Error, wrong validation token');
})
```

I am trying to build this hub challenge in Ruby (Sinatra) and I'm having some trouble converting from Node to Ruby. Any ideas how I can do this?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```ruby
get '/webhook' do
  params['hub.challenge'] if "this_is_my_marker_for_confirmation" == params['hub.verify_token']
end
```